# What's causing this behavior in my Xcode project template?

Tags: xcode

I am wading through the swamps of Xcode project template creation. What's stumping me is this behavior: When I put files into a group, the **last item** in the group shows up as a **folder reference** which contains duplicates of all the files I intended to put in the group.

So when I specify:

```
group/
   foo.h
   foo.m
```

I get:

```
group/
   foo.h
   foo.m/
      foo.h
      foo.m
```

Like so:

[image]

The relevant TemplateInfo.plist xml:

```
  <key>Definitions</key>
    <key>GoogleAnalytics/</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>GoogleAnalytics</string>
    </dict>
    <key>GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics.a</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>libGoogleAnalytics.a</string>
        <key>Group</key>
        <string>GoogleAnalytics</string>
        <key>TargetIndices</key>
        <array>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>GoogleAnalytics/GANTracker.h</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>GANTracker.h</string>
        <key>Group</key>
        <string>GoogleAnalytics</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have come from the fact that the files in my template folder were 'pre-organised' into the locations I wanted them to take in the created project. For instance:

```
GoogleAnalytics/
     libGoogleAnalytics.a
     GANTracker.h
```

The problem was solved by moving the files out of the folder into the root folder of my template:

```
GoogleAnalytics/ (empty)
libGoogleAnalytics.a
GANTracker.h
```

Then the TemplateInfo.plist moves these files into the empty folder at project creation time.

Probably there is another way to work around this, but this way has allowed me to move forward.

For reference, here's an explanatory image I made once I cracked the code of 'Definitions' vs 'Nodes':

[image]